# Weird issue with css media print and transitions chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

Hi I have responsive menus sliding from right and left, only left, or it could be hidden at all. So the main-content is fluid based on this.

I make it fluid by setting proper margin-left and width properties, which looks like this:

```css
    .main-container {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .main-content {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .main-container:not(.menu-hidden) .main-content {
      width: calc(100% - 500px);
      margin-left: 250px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1200px)  {
        .main-container:not(.menu-hidden) .main-content {
            width: calc(100% - 300px);
            margin-left: 300px;
        }
    }

    @media not print {
        .main-content {
            transition: width 1s, margin 1s;
        }
    }

    @media print {
      .main-content {
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        transition: none;
      }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="main-container">
      <div class="main-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque acipsum elit. Donec malesuada purus quis mauris accumsan tempus. Sed ipsum tellus, ultrices posuere odio eget, aliquet convallis urna. Aliquam pulvinar consequat lectus, a gravida quam mattis sit amet. Curabitur molestie fringilla velit sed cursus. Donec a risus diam. In interdum porttitor sem.

          Nullam tincidunt lacus nec leo accumsan aliquet. Integer id justo et urna varius euismod ac non orci. Curabitur sed dignissim nibh, at consectetur augue. Maecenas id tortor id enim maximus laoreet. Etiam id aliquet odio. Integer vel nibh non sapien rhoncus consequat sit amet in nisi. Etiam condimentum vel tortor eu dignissim. Morbi sodales luctus libero non dictum. In fermentum elit et congue efficitur. Vestibulum nunc turpis, posuere vel odio ut, lobortis rutrum sem.
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7hnstfx/2/

I also added the media print so there will be no margins while printing. But with this declarations it doesn't work in chrome if the screen width is bigger then 1200px...
[image]

What is weirdest thing about it, if you remove the transition line, or the declarations in max-width media, it will work. I really run out of ideas what the hell is wrong with it. Anyone can help?

Comment: Check this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=384198

Comment: Ok thanks I thought its a bug. I already manage it by copy the print content (there is not a lot of it) in seperate div and display it. And its still sounds simpler than toggling an animation class.